# Can input features be orthogonal for a neural net?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

Say I want to predict the direction of cloud movement over the next 4 hours.

In one instance I take the cloud positions over the past 1000 minutes and these are the inputs to my neural net. Then I append a humidity variable, temperature variable and a wind speed variable. My input to the neural net looks like this:

```
[cloud_pos1, cloud_pos2, ... cloud_pos1000, humidity, temperature, wind_speed]
```

Will the neural net still learn how to interpret the data given that the humidity, temperature and wind_speed are orthogonal to the 1000 cloud positions?

Would it instead be better to break it up into two different neural nets like this:

`[cloud_pos1, cloud_pos2, ... cloud_pos1000]` and `[humidity, temperature, wind_speed]`

and then combine the outputs of those 2 neural nets into one neural net:

```
[output1, output2]
```

Comment: I wouldn't personally use the word orthogonal here (since that has a precise mathematical meaning and I don't think you intend it that way).  As far as which way is better, why not try both and see what happens?

Comment: I wanted to see if this has a theoretical answer - e.g. it's known that it's best to ensure inputs are centred around 0. Is there a similar thing that is known here? That was my question.

Comment: That's fair.  But, I'd also be careful with how one uses "known" (as in "known to be best").  At best there's empirical evidence to show that things like that (e.g. having data centered at zero) are "better."  And, then only better because it's easier to train--not better because you get better answers in the end (when training is successful).

Comment: All that is to say, that any _theory_ which may legitimately be out there will almost certainly come with a variety of assumptions whose validity will be hard to test given your data.  In practice, one only _knows_ how good methods will be after trying them (on the real, messy data).

Comment: A neural network can certainly learn to ignore some of its inputs, if that's what you're asking.